# Do Google Analytics store sent data to non existing domains?

Tags: dns, google-analytics, tracking

Please, anybody knows: does google analytics store  sent data to non existing domains? If yes, how to get access to them?
The problem is that I forgot to create custom dimensions in google analytics  admin page , but already sent data two weeks ago from web site as:

```
 ga('send','pageview',{'dimension1':placeId,'dimension2':videoId,'dimension3':date});
```

I need to somehow get this data from two weeks ago.

The metric "pageview" I can see, but how to access data from 'dimention1','dimensiot2' if they were not created before? Is it possible?
I already created this dimensions on admin page, but in the report they are empty of cause. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try pulling data using API console, for that date range.

Comment: How can I pulling data from API console, please could you be more precise? Google API Console?

Comment: Check this link: [Query Feed explorer](http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/)
Authorize your google analytics account.
Select your account/profile
Select following dimensions: 
ga:pagePath,ga:dimension1
Metrics: ga:visits
and try to fetch data

Comment: But I did it, and it's empty the results, as dimensions were not created before(( I guess should pull any data for metric "pageviews" whiteout specifying the concrete dimension name. The problem is that I sent data to non existing domain, in the report and  Query Feed explorer the results are empty for the two weeks ago(((of cause I have data after I created domains but from two days ago, not from two weeks((

Comment: Ok, I suggest you to get dimension: page  metrics: visits,pageviews. Hope it should bring some data for you.

One more thing, i would like to confirm that you had your UA and it was sending data properly to your GA account?

Comment: Also, if dimensions were not set in GA interface I think they'll not be available. As they're the placeholders for your data to store.

Comment: Yes, the dimensions were not set in GA interface before I was sending the data, that's why I'm asking. Then the answer is no, it's not possible to get data that was send to dimensions which were not set in GA. Thanks